# Google App Engine Error: app_bucket_name is required

Tags: google-app-engine

We have setup a CI for Google App deployment and it has been working fine until yesterday, we are having trouble deploying to Google App Engine, the error is shown as below:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/projectname/regions/asia-northeast1/operations/f26017a5-ade6-42a6-bd49-1ea287e086 error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/update_flex_deployment/flex_update_resources>2018-10-02T01:19:39.513Z362: app_bucket_name is required.

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Any",
      "value": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.errors.AggregateDebugInfo",
        "debugInfo": {
          "stackEntries": [
            "java.lang.IllegalStateException: app_bucket_name is required.",
            "\tat com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:507)",
            "\tat com.google.apphosting.admin.flex.resources.deployment.UpdateResourcesProducerModule.produceWriteGcsMetadata(UpdateResourcesProducerModule.java:323)",
            "\tSuppressed: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: ",
            "\t\tat com.google.apps.framework.producers.Present.checkSucceeded(Present.java:54)",
            "\t\tat com.google.apphosting.admin.flex.resources.deployment.UpdateResourcesProducerModule.patchDmDeployment(UpdateResourcesProducerModule.java:347)",
            "\tSuppressed: com.google.common.labs.concurrent.LabsFutures$10: GraphFuture{key=@com.google.apps.framework.producers.PrivateVisibility(annotation=\"@com.google.apphosting.admin.flex.resources.deployment.UpdateResourcesProducerModule$NarrowUpdateTargetDm\", module=com.google.apphosting.admin.flex.resources.deployment.UpdateResourcesProducerModule.class) com.google.apphosting.admin.flex.lib.dm.internal.proto.Deployment} failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: app_bucket_name is required.",
            "\t\tat com.google.apps.framework.producers.PresentImpl.get(PresentImpl.java:29)",
            "\t\tat com.google.apphosting.admin.flex.resources.deployment.UpdateResourcesProducerModule.narrowDmUpdated(UpdateResourcesProducerModule.java:444)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
]

Exited with code 1
```

Does anyone know how we could fix this?

P/S: Is this related to Google recent launched [cloud-tasks](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/announcing-cloud-tasks-a-task-queue-service-for-app-engine-flex-and-second-generation-runtimes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117123076#comment2):

> Hi, when you try to deploy, were you overwriting an existing version? If yes, could you please try to deploy a version with a new name instead of overwriting it? It seems the error you observed is a known issue so this will be a workaround for the moment as the App Engine engineering team works on this issue.

I tried deploying to a new version and it works, then I switch it back to overwriting the existing version and it works again. (*works for other applications as well.)

We are still not sure what is the cause of this sudden issue though.

*P/S: I also added permission to my CI service in the bucket with "Storage Legacy Bucket Owner"*

[image]